# Magento (1.x) : How to show bootstrap modal popup

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8, javascript, modal-popup

Is there a way to open the bootstrap modal popup in Magento 1.x?
Like: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp

I also had a look by ctrl+u but didn't find any bootstrap.min.js (or) bootstrap.min.css.

Do Magento 1.x uses bootstrap?

So is it possible to show a bootstrap modal popup in Magento by default?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add these two files using your local.xml file.

```
<action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/bootstrap.min.js</name></action>

<action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/bootstrap.min.css</name></action>
```

make sure these two files exist in your skin location.

Then after you can copy the code from the w3school and use in your frontend template.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering, got that and also I did that. But my concern was that I was expecting that Magento itself provided bootstrap in 1.x. So it means bootstrap is not included in magento by default. Right ?

Comment: default magento 1 not giving the functionality for popup modal.So you need to  add the custom JS and css file and implement it.FYI default magento 2 giving the functionality for popup modal.